# ¿Cómo ejecutar un fichero *.PY desde un fichero *.IPYNB del notebook de Jupyter?

Tags: python, jupyter

Buenas a todos,

estoy trabajando en un notebook en el que me gustaría que aquellos [input] de código que me queden muy largos, pasarlos a un fichero [*.PY] y llamarlos desde el notebook.

La acción de ejecutar desde el Notebook se hacerla, el comando varía entre Linux o Windows. Pero cuando hago esta acción y ejecuto desde el notebook el fichero [*.PY], este no me reconoce ninguna librería cargada o variable previa existente en el notebook (es como si empezase de cero en el [*.PY]...). ¿Hay alguna forma de solucionar esto?

Un posible ejemplo simplificado del problema sería el siguiente:

```
In[1]:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

In[2]:
def f(x):
    return np.exp(-x ** 2)

In[3]:
x = np.linspace(-1, 3, 100)

In[4]:
%run script.py
```

Donde "**script.py**" tiene el siguiente contenido:

```
plt.plot(x, f(x))
plt.xlabel("Eje $x$",fontsize=16)
plt.ylabel("$f(x)$",fontsize=16)
plt.title("Funcion $f(x)$")
```

- En el problema real, el fichero [*.PY] no tiene 4 líneas de código, tiene bastantes más.

Comment: Es posible que agregues tu codigo, para que se pueda reproducir tu error y ayudarte?

Comment: Ya he añadido un ejemplo de código. Lo que realmente pretendo es que el notebook no tenga input masificados de código...

Comment: Hola perdon por revivir pero tengo una duda parecida, nada mas que yo quiero importar un archivo .py en jupyter para poder usar todos los modulos que tiene ese archivo, alguien me podria decir como es?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El comando *mágico* `%run` tiene un parámetro para indicarle que el ejecute el script en el espacio de nombres actual en lugar de crear uno nuevo:

```
%run -i script.py
```

Puedes obtener más información del comando con el `%help` o añadiendo un `?` al final:

```
%run?
```

Comment: Esa es la solución que buscaba Chema, muchísimas gracias! No me deja darle un más +1 porque me dice que aún no tengo puntos suficientes...

Answer (score 0):

Si estas corriendo desde visual studio debes coloca el siguiente formato:

%run "archivo_a_ejecutra.py"

Espero te ayude, slds

Comment: Fijate cómo en la [respuesta aceptada](/a/48863) se explica cómo funciona el comando en cuestión. Leé [answer] y pulsá en [edit] para agregar más detalles.